# Generic C++ Linked list

Tags: c++, generics, linked-list

Below is the code for generic linked list. Code is not working. Not able to figure out what is wrong. Gives no compilation error but generates no output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
    void* data;
    Node* next;
};
void Insert(Node** head,void* k,size_t data_size){
    Node* temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data=malloc(data_size);
    temp->next=*head;
    for(int i=0;i<data_size;i++){
        *((char*)(temp->data) + i) = *((char*)(k )+ i);
    }
    *head=temp;
}
void PrintList(Node* head,void (*fptr)(void*)){
    Node* temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        (*fptr)(temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void PrintInteger(void* k){
    printf("%d",*(int*)(k));
}
void PrintFloat(void* k){
    printf("%f",*(float*)k);
}
int main(){
    int a[]={4,1,9,5};
    float b[]={1.3,7.6,2.5,4.7};
    Node*head=NULL;
    unsigned int_size=sizeof(int);
    unsigned float_size=sizeof(float);
    for(int i=3;i>=0;i++){
        Insert(&head,&a[i],int_size);
    }
    PrintList(head,PrintInteger);
    cout<<endl;
    Node* head2=NULL;
    for(int i=3;i>=0;i++){
        Insert(&head2,&b[i],float_size);
    }
    PrintList(head2,PrintFloat);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like `PrintList` prints anything...

Comment: The loop in `Insert` could be replaced with a call to `memcpy()`.

Comment: @evsheino It calls the `fptr` callback, which prints the element.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Why are you writing C style code in the first place? Do yourself a favor and get a book on modern C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=3;i>=0;i++){
    Insert(&head,&a[i],int_size);
}
```

There is a memory error in your for loops, use "i--" instead of "i++"

Comment: I'm surprised he didn't get a segmentation fault because of this.